# Scala Last Year

Tags: scala, date, variables

I haven't been able to find an answer for this yet for Scala.  I am trying to build a variable in scala for last year and last 2 months, and return in `YYYY-MM-dd` format.  Here is what I have built out.  Right now instead of the variable returning the expected date formatted the way im requesting the variable just returns the expression.  Any thoughts on how I can change my code to present the variable `last_year` with the last year in a string format?

```scala
val last_year=date_sub(current_date()),365)

val last_2=date_sub(current_date()),60)

desired result: last_year= "2021-03-08"
                last_2= "2021-01-08"
```

Comment: the question is not very clear - what did you get from `val last_year=date_sub(current_date()),365)` ? This really should show you the last year (https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/deep-dive-into-apache-spark-datetime-functions-b66de737950a )

Comment: Yeah, not sure why, but if i did a println(last_year) it returned ().  Think I have a working solution tho.

Comment: Why is the "desired" `last_year` a `2021` date? So how are things where you are in the year 2022?

Comment: @jwvh just typo ;) - i'd guess

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same result using the newer `java.time` library in place of the old and outdated `Calendar` and `SimpleDate` options.

```
val prev_yr = java.time.LocalDate.now().minusYears(1L).toString
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I have the answer,  just in case anyone needs this later on:

```
val cal:Calendar=Canlendar.getInstance()
val format=new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd")

cal.add(Calendar.Date,-365)
val prev_yr:String=format.format(cal.getTime)
println(prev_yr)
```

Comment: If _"anyone needs this later on"_ wouldn't it be a good idea to include the required `import` statements? Cleaning up the typos in the code would also be helpful.